# HF characteristics of Liquid Electrical Tape

Tags: insulation, dielectric

Some self-wound toroid inductors from a HF-radio kit are sitting a bit too loose on their PCB for my liking; they stand upright and are only held in place by the thin enamel-coated inductor wire that wraps around the toroid.

I'm thinking of applying a dab of Liquid Electrical Tape to glue the toroid to the PCB, but apart from the Dielectric Strength (of about 1200V/mil) there's no mention of any AC characteristics on the product's website.

Can Liquid Electrical Tape be used for HF purposes without degrading the electrical characteristics of the components around it? Is hot-glue or clear silicone from a hardware shop just as good?

Comment: What on earth is liquid electrical tape?

Comment: It is an air hardening liquid substance that provides electrical insulation. Google will tell you a lot more..

Comment: Is the "tape" going to contact any of the wires, or just the cores?

Comment: There is not enough clearance to just stick the cores to the pcb, so the wires will also get covered with the stuff. Ideally, if this substance is similar to air from a dielectric point of view, I'd like to use it to secure the windings to the toroid as well.

Comment: Hardware store silicone is chemically incompatible with electronic materials, that suitable for electronics a very different substance not sold for home improvement.   Your liquid electrically tape is unlikely to have much specific effect at HF, but any changes to position will alter fine tuning beyond the rough estimate that winding formulas would get you.  Nominally what you want is "Q dope" but who knows if that even still exists.

Comment: If Google knows a lot more then it is a really really really good idea for YOU to provide some links. Expecting people to fetch and carry for you tends ti be unproductive. || NEUTRAL CURE silicone rubber in modest quantities is liable to 'do the job'. I do not know its dielectric properties but mechanically it will last 20+ years if suitably sized to the task. || Non neutral cure should never be used in electronics applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use candle wax. I've seen it done before.